# I made a memory game app and want to add timer that stops when all the cards are matched. Here's my code:-

Tags: android

I made a memory game app and in which I want to add a timer that starts as the activity starts and stops when all the cards are matched and how should I check if all cards are matched? Here's my code:

```
public class game4x4new extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView moves, score, time;
Button reset, submit, start;

private int numberOfElements;
private MemoryButton[] buttons;

private int[] buttonGraphicLocations;
private int[] buttonGraphics;

private MemoryButton selectedButton1;
private MemoryButton selectedButton2;

int flippedtimes = 0;
int match = 0;
int seconds = 0;

AlertDialog.Builder adb;
AlertDialog a;

private boolean isBusy = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game4x4new);

    GridLayout gridlayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout_4x4);

    moves = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    int numColumns = gridlayout.getColumnCount();
    int numRows = gridlayout.getRowCount();

    numberOfElements = numColumns * numRows;
    buttons = new MemoryButton[numberOfElements];

    buttonGraphics = new int[numberOfElements / 2];

    buttonGraphics[0] = R.drawable.blue;
    buttonGraphics[1] = R.drawable.cyan;
    buttonGraphics[2] = R.drawable.green;
    buttonGraphics[3] = R.drawable.grey;
    buttonGraphics[4] = R.drawable.maroon;
    buttonGraphics[5] = R.drawable.pink;
    buttonGraphics[6] = R.drawable.red;
    buttonGraphics[7] = R.drawable.yellow;

    buttonGraphicLocations = new int[numberOfElements];
    shuffleButtonGraphics();

    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < numColumns; c++) {
            MemoryButton tempButton = new MemoryButton(this, r, c, buttonGraphics[buttonGraphicLocations[r * numColumns + c]]);
            tempButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
            tempButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttons[r * numColumns + c] = tempButton;

            gridlayout.addView(tempButton);
        }
    }        

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shuffleButtonGraphics();

            match = 0;
            flippedtimes = 0;
            seconds = 0;
            score.setText("SCORE :");
            moves.setText("MOVES :");
            time.setText("TIME :");
        }
    });
}

    protected void shuffleButtonGraphics()
    {
        Random rand= new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            buttonGraphicLocations[i]= i % (numberOfElements / 2);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfElements;i++)
        {
            int temp= buttonGraphicLocations[i];
            int swapIndex = rand.nextInt(16);

            buttonGraphicLocations[i]=buttonGraphicLocations[swapIndex];
            buttonGraphicLocations[swapIndex]=temp;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(isBusy)
        return;

        MemoryButton button= (MemoryButton) v;

        if(selectedButton1==null)
        {
            selectedButton1=button;
            selectedButton1.flipped();
            return;
        }
        if(selectedButton1.getId()==button.getId())
        {
            return;
        }
        if (selectedButton1.getFrontDrawableId()==button.getFrontDrawableId())
        {
            button.flipped();

            button.setMatched(true);
            selectedButton1.setMatched(true);

            selectedButton1.setEnabled(false);
            button.setEnabled(false);

            selectedButton1=null;

            flippedtimes++;
            match++;
            moves.setText("MOVES : " + flippedtimes);
            score.setText("SCORE : " + match);

            return;
        }

        else
        {
            selectedButton2=button;
            selectedButton2.flipped();
            isBusy=true;
            flippedtimes++;
            moves.setText("MOVES : " + flippedtimes);

            final Handler handler= new Handler();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    selectedButton2.flipped();
                    selectedButton1.flipped();
                    selectedButton1=null;
                    selectedButton2=null;
                    isBusy=false;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe state reason for negative voting? Dont just go on marking questions downvote, this will by no means improve the question quality or encourage the asker to have productive discussion.

Comment: Please consider making a [mcve]. Also explain your question better. Right now I have to read your code to understand what you mean by 'matched'. Additionally, your code isn't formatted correctly. The top line is not included in the code block. Please move everything in four spaces. This is easily doable in any IDE, for example by selecting everything and hitting tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a timer when the game starts. After two cards are revealed check if they match. If they do, check if there are any unmatched cards left. If yes don't stop the timer. If no, stop the timer.